# Python: Numpy version is not downgrading

Tags: python, numpy, package

I am trying to import the keras library which causes the following error code:

> AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'typeDict'

Already found the reason for the error:

> This means you are using a NumPy version that removed the deprecated ways AND the library you are using wasn't updated to match that version (uses something like np.typeDict instead of np.sctypeDict).

I wanted to downgrade numpy to an older version (1.21) to fix the issue.
BUT no matter what I am trying to downgrade numpy, it seems like it's stuck on version 1.24.1.

When trying `pip3 install --upgrade numpy==1.21` in the terminal it says:
`Requirement already up-to-date: numpy==1.21 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.21.0)`
But when checking the numpy version in my editor with `import numpy print(numpy.__version__)`it's still version 1.24.1. I have already uninstalled the numpy package and reinstalled the older version but nothing changes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd guess that the Anaconda environment that is being use when running from the editor is different to the one that you are installing NumPy 1.21 in. What editor are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code. Do you know how to install Numpy to the Anaconda environment I am using?

Comment: In VS Code, in the bottom right of the window (or potentially the bottom left in older versions), there should be a bit (assuming you have a Python file open) that says "{} Python" and next to it a bit that gives the Python version and Anconda environment, e.g., "3.9.16 {'base': conda}". From your question it looks like you are installing numpy 1.21 in the "base" environment, so if the Anaconda environment shown by VS Code does not say {'base': conda} it will be looking in a different environment. You can try clicking on that and switch the interpreter to the one in "base".

Comment: Or, you could install NumPy in the environment you're using by opening a terminal (you can do this from VS Code with the "Terminal" tab, or open an Anaconda enabled Powershell Prompt terminal from, e.g., Anaconda Navigator (or just any terminal if on Linux/Mac), typing `conda activate blah`, where `blah` is the name of your environment and then running the `pip` commands from your question.

Comment: The second one fixed it for me, thank you so much!! :) 
Only one small thing: I can import all the necessary modules now, but the modules are now underlined in yellow. Do you know what could be the reason for this? When hovering over it says 'Import "numpy" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)' The given report is not really helping.

Comment: As far as I know, Pylance should pick up any packages installed in the conda environment that VS Code displays in the bottom right corner (https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/330#issuecomment-687692138). If not, then restarting VS Code might help.

Comment: Yep, just switching the environment to the base and back to the new env solved it. Thank you for your help!